# Upload Folders to Server in C# Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I know how to upload files/images in asp.net using fileuploader control.i want to upload folders not a single file.i want to upload whole asp.net website to another server (may or may not using FTP) using C# Coding.
Even i tried to make a zip and upload but we can not upload zip too....
what is the best way to upload whole DIrectories/Folders/Files to server using c# coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use of ftpwebclass in C# for uploading a folder using ftp
check out this [link](http://oops-solution.blogspot.in/2012/02/file-uploading-using-ftp-in-cnet.html)

Comment: i want to copy contents some where else on server.how i can copy folders on server to any distination or rename folders etc?

Answer (score 1):

C# has build-in FTPrequest class where you can create folders, upload files, delete files etc.

If you want to upload folders from a webpage, you cannot use this technology in the browser, then you will have to use a rich-client such as Java, Flash or similar plugin.

If you can provide the users with a Windows or Mac client, you can use C# (either .NET or Mono)  for the FTP transfer.

ZIP files arent a problem for ASP.net nor C#, but you still only upload 1 file (zip-archive) and then its up to the server to unzip it using eg. C#. Look at 7-Zip which is opensource, then you might get some ideas too.

You could also just try and use the build-in lib for it (compression):

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10050636/how-to-compress-and-decompress-file-in-c.aspx

Comment: i have  asp.net web site template on server.how can i code to copy those contents to any subfolder(sub domain on that server).how i can code it in asp.net c#?

Comment: hi @Methew please post your new question as a new question. :o) I will try to answer it there. Each question in StackOverflow has to have its own thread.

Comment: quick answer though: you'll need to code something that copies each file one at a time. There is no build in "copy folder" function in .net