# Asp.net : Upload directory using c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload, uploader

I have have a solution now to upload multiple files using (**drag drop**) technique by JavaScript and jQuery, but I need to find a way to upload **folder** with all of it is content like **Google drive** . Is this possible?

Comment: from the description on [google drive](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2424368) I learn that you need a java applet to accomplish that. Is that suitable to you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload Folders to Server in C# Asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308334/upload-folders-to-server-in-c-sharp-asp-net)

Comment: No, it's not possible with plain client side or server side code you'll have to use applet/plugin/extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not do this, only with a browser.

You will have to use a custom client for this.

But a simple method will be `Ask the user to ZIP the folder and upload the zip using the file-upload control`.
Then on the server end, you can un-zip and read the content.